# Some elements are taller in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When checking my site in IE some elements get rendered "taller" than in other browsers - seemingly with nothing in common that i can find (edit: turned out they all contained svg elements). It's like they have a fixed height even though they don't.

Example in IE: https://ibb.co/gScRD5

In chrome (as expected): https://ibb.co/bPEOt5

(Project is in react with css modules but I've summarised the css that's combined)

The button:

```
<a href="/kontakta-oss/" className={styles.cta}>
  Kontakta oss
  <Svg src={chevronSvg} className={styles.ctaChevron} />
</a>
```

And the its scss:

```
.cta {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(64, 142, 180, 0.75);
    fill: #fff;
    transition: background .1s;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.cta-chevron {
    width: 1rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are your class-names obfuscated?

Comment: Webpack. This is the production build. Mainly to save a few bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<svg>` element in your `<a>`. IE is giving it a height of approximately 150px which is what gives the `<a>` a larger height.

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    id="Capa_1"
    viewBox="0 0 238.003 238.003"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xml:space="preserve"
    version="1.1"
>
    ...
</svg>
```

If you open F12 Tools in IE and remove the `<svg>` element then the `<a>` box is sized correctly.

IE doesn't seem to be correctly inferring the SVG's intrinsic height - you can fix this by adding an explicit `height="16px"` attribute to the `<svg>` element, then it will render correctly.

Comment: Oh.. Completely missed this. Thanks!